# How do I limit phpStorm to open files just from my defined scope?

Tags: file-search, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I would like to know if it is possible to use this dialog window filtered to just one scope. I find this very useful, but unfortunately frameworks have tons of files I never want to edit, and therefore its a waste of my time when they pop up in this search.

[image]

If it is not currently possible then what is the best method of requesting this feature from intelliJ IDEA?

Comment: [Log in](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and create feature issue.

Comment: Actually PhpStorm mustn't add file from framework or external libs in this search if `Include non-project files` is not checked. Rather you add them in project on incorrect way.

Comment: I figured that might be suggested. But I want to use scopes because I can easily edit a scope and add more folders to a scope. Either way I'm using Laravel and I'd just like to be able to include like the public folder and the resource folder in this search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigate | File` doesn't currently support scopes. Please vote for [IDEA-107386](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107386) if you miss this feature.
Note that library files shouldn't normally be included in search if `Include non-project files` is off

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of the exact feature request. Is there any way to include several sibling files and folders in a project and add more as needed?